# Google maps showing correct location with latitude longitude but also shows nearest road

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps to show the user location based on the latitude and longitude passed in the query. It shows fine with a green arrow. But the map also shows a letter pin with the nearest road/address.

How do I hide the letter pin and ensure only the green arrow is shown? The URL I use is:

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=latitude,longitude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution, might help someone else.

Using this url: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:latitude,longitude

will ensure the letter pin only shows at this location and does not find the nearest road/address.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @lostInTransit - it's fine to self-answer your own question. You should mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I have to wait for some time before I can do that (SE policies!). So can't right now.